# How do I find the energy difference between two points of a gravitational gradient?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, calculus

What I'm ultimately trying to figure out is how to calculate only the potential energy attributed to the differences in the force of gravity at two distances from the Earth's center of gravity.

Comment: Do you know how how to integrate?

Comment: @Timaeus not really...

Comment: Then there might not be a satisfying answer for you. The force changes magnitude but the rate it changes matters so it doesn't depend on just the force here and the force there but on the details on how it changed here there and every where in between. Calculus was invented to solve problems just like this, and there isn't a real alternative that isn't equivalent to calculus. Sometimes someone can just hand you the result from calculus and tell you to plug in numbers here and there. In which case C-GmM/r could work where r is the distance to the center of the earth.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I'm not interested in the acceleration energy. For example: The earth pulls on me with 200lbs of force at sea level, and some fraction of that at higher altitudes. I want to calculate the difference in those forces. @Timaeus

Comment: If you have two forces you can subtract them, but the change in potential energy will depend on whether the force decreased linearly, quadratically, exponentially, logarithmically, or something else as it changed from on to the other. And I don't think acceleration energy is a thing.

Comment: Do u want to find the change in potential energy between 2 points in a G field?

Comment: Is the difference in the force of gravity between two distances linear?

Comment: @slhulk I believe so.

Comment: @Timaeus on earth force decreases according to the inverse square law right?

Comment: @slhulk If it were a perfect sphere it would go like $F=GM_\oplus m/r^2$ where $r$ is the distance to the center.

Comment: I believe joshperry here wants to consider earth as a sphere guessing from his question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two points A and B at distances r and s away from the center of the earth. And a mass of m is positioned at both points.

therefore the G potential energy of m at A be,

-GMm/r

and at B,

-GMm/s

Where G is the gravitational constant.
M is the mass of earth

Then the difference in these two results in the difference in the gravitational potential energy.

If the mass is bright to B from A the work that has to be done on m is,

-GMm/s - (-GMm/r)

=GMm (1/r - 1/s)

Answer (score 0):

The gravitational force is proportional to 1/r^2, where r is the distance from the center of the earth to the position you want to evaluate.  As the gravitational force g at the surface of the Earth is known, you can set up a proportion to find the unknown **g**.

Suppose one of the distances is 10 kilometers above the surface.  The surface is 6,371 kilometers from the center.

9.80665 / **g** = (1/6371^2) / (1/6381^2) = (6381/6371)^2 = 1.00314

1.00314 **g** = 9.80665

**g** = 9.77595

Work the same ratio for the other height to find the unknown **g** there.

Then compute potential energy at each height by multiplying the mass of the object you wish to evaluate by the height and the appropriate **g**.  Take the difference between the two potential energies.

At least that's the way [Mr. Hand's Science and Math Site](https://www.mansfieldct.org/Schools/MMS/staff/hand/lawsgravaltitude.htm) suggests it can be done.